# What is the reason $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ is computed the way it is being computed?

Tags: calculus

Say there is an equation $y=x^2$. I know if we differentiate this equation we get $$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}·1=2x·\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dx}\Longrightarrow\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=2x.$$

The definition of $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ is differentiating $y$ with respect to $x$, and $\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dx}$ is differentiating $x$ with respect to $x$. I understand $x^2$ becomes $2x$ by differentiating $x$ with respect to $x$, but I do not understand the $y$ part. Shouldn't it become $0$ from $y$? Shouldn't we consider $y$ as constant since we are not differentiating with respect with $y$?

Comment: In your first line you define $y$ as a function of $x$, ie. $y(x) = x^{2}$ so it's not constant upon differentiation w.r.t $x$. Do you know the definition of the differential operator $\frac{d}{dx}$?

Comment: I think d/dx only means to differentiate

Comment: Yes, but I mean, do you know *what is differentiation doing*?
If you don't know what I mean, you can read about the definition of the derivative [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnOfDerivative.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Shouldn't it become 0 from y? Shouldn't we consider y as constant since we are not differentiating with respect with y?

Let's say $y=x^2$.   That is, $y$ is a dependent variable.   Such is *not* constant; *nor* could it be "held constant with respect to $x$" for a partial derivative (which this is not).   So therefore its derivative with respect to $x$ is clearly not zero (except when evaluated at $x=0$).   We evaluate it by substitution.$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{
\mathrm d x}y & =\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm dx}x^2 \\[1ex]&= 2x\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm dx}x\\[1ex]&=2x\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh that's what I was looking for !  Thanks a lot ^^

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\frac {dx}{dx} =\frac {d}{dx}(x)$ means derivative of $ y=x$ with respect to $x$.

When you differentiate $y=x$ with respect to $x$ you get $\frac {d}{dx}(x) =1$

Usually we do not include $\frac {dx}{dx}$ when differentiating $ y=x^2$.

We  simply write  $\frac {dy}{dx}= 2x$

Comment: That is correct, you do not need to include it in your calculations.

Comment: But isn't (dy/dy)*y=1? So I thought dy/dx*y must be different since it is not differentiating with respect to y.

Comment: d/dx* y=d/dx* x^2   so  since we're differentiating with respect to x on both sides, I think the way they are being differentiated should be different since they are two different things

Comment: Note that (dy/dy)=1 and (dy/dy)*y=y .   dy/dx*y does not simplify unless you know what is y.

Comment: Oh yeah  I meant d/dy * y =1  ^^

Comment: $d/dxy$ is not well defined. If you know that $y=x^2$, then $(d/dx)y = 2x.$

Comment: Please do not use * for differentiation purpose. Keep it for multiplication only.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!